# Scale ImageView within FrameLayout ontouch

Tags: android, scale

Can anyone help me with scaling(resizing) image on touch with 2 fingers ? I have frameLayout and i dynamic append imageViews. And i want to scale image.Can i resolve this problem without using Matrix?

Move is working correctly i move image on frameLayout. But scaling dont know . Can you put me some link or library how to resolve that? I found some solutions but problem waas that scale was working only within imageView. framelayout and imageView. ImageView must have width and height fill_parent and u can just scale and move image within this imageView. But i want scale ImageView within this FrameLayout. I put my code and this working fine when i add 3 images i can handle this images single. But i need resize aswell. Thanks for your post

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_images_per_category);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    selectedImages = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("selectedImages");
    relativeLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customLayutForImages);

    for(int i=0; i< selectedImages.size(); i++) {
        ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(SelectedImagesActivity.this);
        Uri u =  selectedImages.get(i);
        mImageView.setImageURI(u);



        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 300,300 );
        relativeLayout.addView(mImageView, params);
        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }

enter code   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;

            mode = MOVE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            mode = ZOOM;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == ZOOM) {
                //WHAT TO DO HERE
            }
            if (mode == MOVE) {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view
                        .getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
            break;
    }
    relativeLayout.invalidate();
    return true;
}here
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this doc using [ScaleGestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html#scale)

If not you can use this [library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

Comment: I used the second library and i used thant example ,image zoom is working OK, but its still return to default resolution after zoom in or zoom out when i leave the screen.  WHen  fingers leave the screen image is return to default. Is this ok or i need to someting add? Maybe same

Comment: Well this library helps you to zoom in and zoom out . What you're asking is to resize the image based on that zoom in and zoom out , you need something else if you want to achieve that.